# Make symbol layer icon-size zoom invariant

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am attempting to place a hexagon (centred over co-ordinates) which I can interact with, hover/onclick. The method I am using is to LoadImage(..._Hexagon.png) and then addLayer. Eventually the idea is to have many hexagons over specific areas.

I have obtained the desired interaction with the shape, but I would like this layer to be invariant under zoom ***(ie I have the hexagons cover an area of x square km at all times regardless of zoom)***. Is there an efficient way to do this? Will another method be better? etc

Thank you in advance for any and all advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to scale an icon such that it gets bigger as you zoom in, you can use an exponential scale:

`"icon-scale": ["*", ["interpolate", ["exponential", 2], ["zoom"]], SCALE]`

where `SCALE` is some constant you pick.

It probably makes more sense to actually generate hexagonal polygon data (eg, using [Turf](http://turfjs.org/docs/#hexGrid)), and displaying that though.